# Pricepeep Browser extension causing the issue to jquery javascript code present on web pages

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon

We are developing a website in which we are making use of JQuery library and some of JQuery plugins like cycle, countdown, jcarousal and so on. Recently we found that if our website users download and install browser plugin/extension called "Pricepeep"; then they keep getting lots of javascript errors while browsing our website pages. If they go to Browser's tools option and disable this extension then again everything works good and no javascript error occurs while opening the web pages. I tried searching about this issue caused by Pricepeep but haven't got anything useful. As a business owner we can't tell our user to disable this Pricepeep add-on; instead of that we will have to modify our code. I am suspecting that Pricepeep also load its own jquery and because of that our Jquery variables gets vanished. Has anybody observed such issue with any such browser add-on/extension/BHO.

Comment: No, you do not need to modify your code to fix **completely broken** browser toolbars (which are usually more on the malware side than on the "useful software" side). The proper solution is indeed to tell your users to uninstall the crappy toolbar - or even better, complain to the developers of that toolbar so they can fix their crap.

Comment: Thanks ThiefMaster. I got your point. But the real problem is end user can install n numbers of browser add-on which may use its own jQuery version internally. So as a best practice what you will recommend while building the JQuery based website? Should we always load our required JQuery in <head> and call the jQuery.noConflict mechanism to create our own JQ namespace and use it all over the place and get rid of standard $ and jQuery global variables to avoid any such conflicts?

Comment: **No** properly written browser addon will inject its own jQuery into the page. *If* something actually needs to inject jQuery it's supposed to do it in a way that does not break anything on the page (e.g. by injecting it and then immediately using `$.noConflict(true)`). So you *can* safely do it like pretty much every other site: Ignore the fact that crappy extensions can break things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue with the js noConflict and have rolled out an update.